# xDB not storing any Interactions

Tags: mongodb, sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-xdb

**Update:** So the issue was that my application Global.asax.cs did not derive from Sitecore.Web.Application.

So I have just installed Sitecore 8 with MongoDB 2.6.11.

For test purposes I placed the code below in page load event to activate the goal I have created earlier in sitecore.

The goal was created successfully via deploy and publish. I have also confirmed the item id of the goal is correct.

```
    if (Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.IsActive && Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.CurrentPage != null)
    {
       Sitecore.Data.Items.Item GoaltoTrigger = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem("{EDA8EA2C-7AF5-4D0F-AF76-A9C4E6BD7169}");
       if (GoaltoTrigger != null)
       {
           Sitecore.Analytics.Data.Items.PageEventItem registerthegoal = new Sitecore.Analytics.Data.Items.PageEventItem(GoaltoTrigger);
           Sitecore.Analytics.Model.PageEventData eventData = Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.CurrentPage.Register(registerthegoal);
           eventData.Data = GoaltoTrigger["Description"];
           Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.Interaction.AcceptModifications();
       }
    }
    Session.Abandon();
```

Sadly this did not work and I can not see the goal in xDB under Interactions.

Other things I have looked into is that my layout definitely has the tag

```
<sc:VisitorIdentification runat="server" />
```

my Global.asax implements Sitecore.Web.Application

```
public class Global : Sitecore.Web.Application
```

Yet no luck. The Interactions are no where to be seen in Mongo (using mongo shell and roboMongo to look up the collection). Am I missing something else?

[image]

[image]

**Sitecore Error**

```
ManagedPoolThread #3 16:43:00 INFO  Job ended: Sitecore.ListManagement.Analytics.UnlockContactListsAgent (units processed: )
12980 16:43:05 INFO  Cache created: '[no name]' (max size: 976KB, running total: 2918MB)
12980 16:43:05 INFO  Cache created: '[no name]' (max size: 976KB, running total: 2919MB)
12980 16:43:05 INFO  Cache created: '[no name]' (max size: 976KB, running total: 2920MB)
12980 16:43:05 INFO  Cache created: '[no name]' (max size: 976KB, running total: 2921MB)
12980 16:43:05 INFO  Cache created: '[no name]' (max size: 976KB, running total: 2922MB)
ManagedPoolThread #5 16:43:06 ERROR Failed to perform MaxMind lookup
ManagedPoolThread #5 16:43:06 ERROR Failed to perform GeoIp lookup for 127.0.0.1
Exception: Sitecore.Analytics.Lookups.CannotParseResponseException
Message: Unexpected format. Cannot parse the MaxMind response for IP address: 127.0.0.1

Source: Sitecore.Analytics
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Lookups.MaxMindProvider.GetInformationByIp(String ip)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Lookups.GeoIpManager.GetDataFromLookupProvider(GeoIpHandle geoIpHandle)

12980 16:43:08 INFO  Cache created: 'WebUtil.QueryStringCache' (max size: 19KB, running total: 2922MB)
2700 16:43:08 INFO  HttpModule is being initialized
12360 16:43:08 INFO  HttpModule is being initialized
7068 16:43:08 INFO  HttpModule is being initialized
9940 16:43:10 INFO  [Experience Analytics]: Reduce agent found zero segments to process
ManagedPoolThread #1 16:43:10 INFO  Job started: Sitecore.ListManagement.Analytics.UnlockContactListsAgent
ManagedPoolThread #1 16:43:10 INFO  Job ended: Sitecore.ListManagement.Analytics.UnlockContactListsAgent (units processed: )
```

Comment: Could you please clarify the following: **1)** Is there `Interactions` collection in your `analytics` MongoDB database? **2)** Are there *any* documents in that collection? **3)** Why are you using page event registration API instead of associating the goal with your content item?

Comment: Hi @DmytroShevchenko I can confirm 1) there is Interactions collection in my analytics MongoDB with 4 indexes. 2) No documents in Interactions collection 3) The plan is to put this goal creation in a button click event but to keep things simple and for test purposes I have placed the code in page load. See image above. Thanks

Comment: Are there any errors in the Sitecore logs?

Comment: Currently running it through powershell (see image above) and can not see anything exciting. Does that help? Sitecore I can see error (see above)

Comment: Which exact version of Sitecore are you using?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Triggering goals

First of all, this is the correct way to trigger a goal:

```cs
if (Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.IsActive)
{
    if (Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.CurrentPage != null)
    {
        var goalId = new Sitecore.Data.ID("{EDA8EA2C-7AF5-4D0F-AF76-A9C4E6BD7169}");

        Sitecore.Analytics.Data.Items.PageEventItem goalToTrigger =
            Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.DefinitionItems.PageEvents[goalId];

        if (goalToTrigger != null)
        {
            Sitecore.Analytics.Model.PageEventData eventData =
                Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.CurrentPage.Register(goalToTrigger);
        }
        else
        {
            Sitecore.Diagnostics.Log.Error("Goal with ID " + goalId + " does not exist", this);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Sitecore.Diagnostics.Log.Error("Tracker.Current.CurrentPage is null", this);
    }
}
else
{
    Sitecore.Diagnostics.Log.Warn("The tracker is not active. Unable to register the goal.", this);
}
```

You should not attempt to change the event data after you've registered it.

Also, you should not call `Interaction.AcceptModifications()`, as this method is something xDB uses internally at some point.

`CurrentPage.Register()` is the only thing that you need to do.

## Ending the session

I don't recommend using `Session.Abandon()`. It will probably result in saving your interaction to the collection database, but this way you are disrupting the normal flow of Sitecore's session. One of the problems that this may lead to is that the interaction's contact will remain locked for 21 minutes (or whatever your session timeout is set to + 1 minute).

Instead, for testing purposes, I recommend you to set session timeout to 1 minute and just wait for 1 minute after your last page request. This setting is located in the ***Web.config*** as an attribute of `<sessionState>`.

## Troubleshooting interaction saving issues

1. Make sure that the `analytics` connection string is set properly.
2. Make sure that you have a license for xDB. You can see the list of available licenses in Sitecore Control Panel –> Administration –> Installed licenses.
   a) In Sitecore 8.0 or lower, the license name is `Sitecore.OMS`.
   b) In Sitecore 8.1 it's `Sitecore.xDB.base`.
3. Make sure that xDB and its tracking subsystem are enabled.
   a) In Sitecore 8.0 or lower, `Analytics.Enabled` should be set to `true` in the ***Sitecore.Analytics.config***.
   b) In Sitecore 8.1, both `Xdb.Enabled` and `Xdb.Tracking.Enabled` should be set to `true` in the ***Sitecore.Xdb.config***.
4. Tracking should also be enabled on site definitions.
   a) In Sitecore 8.0 or lower, go to the `<sites>` section in the ***Web.config*** and check that `enableAnalytics` is **not** set to `false` on `<site name="website">` or whatever site you are using.
   b) In Sitecore 8.1, you should ensure that `enableTracking` is set to `true` for your site in the ***Sitecore.config***.
5. Try making several page requests instead of just one before letting the session to expire.
6. Try disabling robot detection by setting both `Analytics.Robots.IgnoreRobots` and `Analytics.AutoDetectBots` to `false` in the ***Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.config***. If interactions are saved after this, I will update my answer with further instructions.
7. If nothing helps, go through the steps listed in the article [**Troubleshooting xDB data issues**](https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/977445).

Comment: Thanks for this. I will give this a go and get back to you either way.

Comment: In 8.1 `Analytics.Enabled` is moved to Sitecore.Xdb.config and renamed to `Xdb.Tracking.Enabled`. Also remember `enableTracking="true"` on your site definitions (8.1).

Comment: The line below is giving me null. Keep in mind I have not created a page event just a goal itself. Sitecore.Analytics.Data.Items.PageEventItem goalToTrigger =
            Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.DefinitionItems.PageEvents[goalId];

Comment: @Bobby goals *are* page events. A special kind. In any case, I don't believe that goal registration is your main issue here. Deal with your problems one at a time. First you need to ensure interactions (web visits) are saved to MongoDB. I would try to remove the goal registration code and just visit a few normal pages after you try each of the steps that I described.

Comment: So the issue was that my application Global.asax.cs did not derive from Sitecore.Web.Application. All working now. Thanks for the troubleshoot link. I will update the question.